# Symfony 4 Search Form by entity type (M:N), results show only fields from form, other missing

Tags: forms, symfony, search, doctrine

I have 2 entities: Worker (id, firstname) and Profession (id, title).

I have some workers with one or more professions.
When I open website I see worker data with all professions from workers. For example:

ID: 2 - Tom - teacher, driver

Next, I created search form where i can choose by entity type some of profession and click search.
After this I see list of workers but some o professions dissapear, I see only this professions what i choose in form. For example when I try search drivers:

ID: 2 - Tom - driver    (text: teacher profession dissapear from results)

It should be ID: 2 - Tom - teacher, driver (same like before but list should show only persons with driver profession, but text about rest of profession should be here to read)

Code from search controller:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Worker::class);
$form = $this->createForm(WorkerSearchType::class, null, [
    'method' => 'GET',
]);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $professions = $form->get('professions')->getData();

    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->select('w, p')
        ->leftJoin('w.professions', 'p');

    if (isset($professions) && count($professions) > 0) {
        $qb->andWhere('p.id IN (:professions)')
            ->setParameter('professions', $professions);
    }

    $qb = $qb->getQuery();
}

if (!isset($qb)) {
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->select('w')
        ->orderBy("w.created", 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();
}
```

Fragment of form type:

```
$builder
    ->add('professions', EntityType::class, array(
        'class'         => Profession::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'multiple'     => true,
        'expanded'     => false,
        'required'     => false,
        'label'        => false,
    ));
```